# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - (1/n)^y)^n $?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate the following. Say $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is given,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - (1/n)^y)^n $

I **tried**:

Only found some similarity with the formula for $e^{-1}$. That is,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - (1/n))^n = e^{-1}$

Comment: What is $y$...?

Comment: @amsmath oh, I wrote $y$ as a given real number.

Comment: You will need to distinguish cases: $y>0$, $y=0$, and $y<0$. For the most interesting case, $y>0$, write it as $[(1-n^{-y})^{-n^y}]^{-n^{1-y}}$, and take into account that $(1-n^{-y})^{-n^{y}}\to e$.